# How to install an application on android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, cmd, adb, android-install-apk

When i enter "adb install asdasd.apk" to cmd returns "error:device not found". How can I fix this?

Comment: follow this tutorial http://www.botskool.com/geeks/how-install-apk-files-android-windows-sdk-emulator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, familiarize yourself with a concept of AVD. That's basically an instance of the emulator - it has a bunch of settings, like the Android version to use and screen size and an SD card image.

You cannot install stuff "in the emulator" - you can only install stuff into a specific AVD. For that, you need to create and run an AVD first. For that, use "AVD Manager" from Eclipse or standalone.

Under the Android SDK folder in Explorer, run "AVD Manager". Choose an AVD (or create a new one if you don't have any). Select, click "Start".

Comment: I have already created a device. I have been using AVD for a long time for my projects this is not the first time. I tried to integrate my app with facebook. That's why I need facebook on the emulator

Comment: Sorry, I was misled by your choice of words. Can you see the AVD in the Devices window in Eclipse? Can you do `adb -e shell` into it?

Comment: Try creating/starting a new fresh AVD.

Answer (score 5):

Just copy that apk file into ( D:\android-sdk\platform-tools ) android sdk platform tools.

```
 and then open the cmd prompt. 

 then, come into that platform tools path in cmd prompt.

 then, give like this in cmd -- adb install (appName).apk 

 wait few minutes and get success respomse in cmd prompt..
```

Comment: For windows user sdk platform tools might be here C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools

Answer (score 0):

Does the emulator show up when you run the following command?

`adb devices`

If not, you might have to boot up the AVD first, but if I remember correctly it should be starting it up by itself.

Comment: Have you downloaded a system image for the AVD via the SDK manager?

Comment: I have SDK and AVD manager ,I have been using those two in eclipse However I don't know what a system image is?

Comment: Under the Android SDK folder, run "AVD Manager". Choose an AVD (or create a new one if you don't have any). Select, click "Start".

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a new emulator for your project? And are you using Eclipse? Eclipse has an ADT plugin which is useful as it allows you to open the AVD manager through it. This plugin will give you this option in the Windows tool bar of Eclipse: Windows>AVD manager.

Create a new project based on the emulator and click the run button which will install your project onto the emulator. If you have an Android device I recommend turning USB development mode in your phones settings and running your project straight onto your device as it will be a lot faster. Hope this helps

Comment: I'm trying to install facebook to android emulator. I have Facebook.apk to install.

Answer (score 0):

this is what i did : 
first run the "AVD Manager"-> choose an AVD ->  click "Start"

> immediately after

you click on "Start" 
use command on cmd as,

> adb install asdasd.apk

then in my case (Windows), asked to place .apk file in data/local/tmp/
what i did was copy and paste .apk file into data/local/tmp
and again use command

> adb install asdasd.apk

then cmd prompted-> Success

You can also use command

> adb devices

command for check whether emulator is in the list

Actually you may need to run AVD several times